# La animación del hover deja un rastro extraño al desactivarse

Tags: html, css, wordpress

buenas y gracias de antemano por atender mi duda. Recientemente es que he aprendido a manejar HTML y CSS, resulta que todo iba bien hasta que me he encontrado con esto...

[image: Rastro de animación abajo]

[image: Rastro de animación a la derecha]

Como podéis ver se notan claramente dos cosas principalmente: las letras cambian de su posición y se mueven ligeramente durante el proceso y lo peor (y que más me molesta) es una especie de rastro que deja el hover al contraerse.

No sé exactamente qué lo ocasiona ni tampoco cómo se llaman estos tipos de errores, he intentado buscar por mi cuenta antes de recurrir a poner yo mismo un post pero... no he sido capaz de encontrar nada.

Lo único que tengo claro es que a pesar de que se nota en otros navegadores en Google Chrome se remarca mucho más, os adjunto el código.

```css
.caja {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /*margin: 10px -140px;*/
  transform: scale(1); 
}

.boton {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: poppins;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #0c71c3;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 8px 17px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}  

.caja:hover {
   transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
   transform: scale(1.05);    
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
    <button href="#" class="boton">Aprender más</button>
</div>
```

Comment: El comportamiento del código provisto no es igual al de tus imágenes, no puedo reproducir el problema